# Entity Framework : the selected stored procedure or functions returns no columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, web, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am getting this error from Entity Framework while creating a complex type. May of them are telling to user `SET FMTONLY OFF` but for me it is not working. The stored procedure is returning the column but the columns it returns are not fixed. it sometimes returns a table with 2 columns or 4 columns. I am using Entity Framework 5.0. Any help will be much appreciated

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_hcube_rack] 
    @hcapmaxmodule int
AS   
BEGIN
    DECLARE @col_name varchar(1055)       
    DECLARE @count  int, @cnt int
    DECLARE @col varchar(255), @cmd nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    DECLARE getinfo CURSOR FOR
        SELECT c.name 
        FROM sys.tables t 
        JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
        WHERE t.Name = 'Hydrcube_rack_mapping'

    OPEN getinfo
  
    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @col

    CREATE TABLE #column_tbl (ID INT, tempUserName varchar(MAX))

    SET @cnt = 1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @cmd = N'SELECT @count = COUNT(*) 
                        FROM Hydrcube_rack_mapping 
                        WHERE Hcap_modules = ' + CAST(@hcapmaxmodule AS nvarchar(20)) + 
                        ' AND ['+@col+'] IS NULL'

        EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, @ParmDefinition = N'@count INT OUTPUT', @count = @count OUTPUT;

        IF (@count = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @col_name = CONCAT(@col, ',', @col_name)

            INSERT INTO #column_tbl (ID, tempUserName) 
            VALUES (@cnt, @col_name)

            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
        END 

        FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
    END

    CLOSE getinfo
    DEALLOCATE getinfo

    SELECT TOP 1 @col_name = tempUserName 
    FROM #column_tbl 
    ORDER BY ID DESC

    SELECT @cmd = 'SELECT ' + LEFT(@col_name, LEN(@col_name) - 1) +
                  ' FROM Hydrcube_rack_mapping ' + 
                  ' WHERE Hcap_modules = ' + CAST(@hcapmaxmodule AS nvarchar(20)) 
 
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
END
GO
```

Output from the stored procedure:

```
hcuberack|kit14_1|kit13_1|kit12_1|kit7_2|kit6_2|kit4_3|kit3_4|Hcap_mod|id
24       |1      |1      |1      |1     |1     |0     |0     |24      |24
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but avoid using the `sp_` name prefix for user stored procedures per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments).

Comment: Thank you Dan For the Suggestion. will update the name

Comment: Each of the insert statements inside the cursor will be outputting a rowcount event, which is likely confusing EF. Have you tried adding `set nocount on` at the very beginning of your stored procedure?

Comment: Yup I did add the `Set Nocount on` at the beginning but no sucess.